# Frame layout in CSS: divs or iframes?

Tags: css, iframe

I am a newbie to html5 and CSS.

I try to replace my old frames with html5 and CSS.

I have made this little test with divs, which in one example works OK.

Maybe I should continue with the divs, but for some reason iframes sounds better than divs for replacing old frames so I tried to repeat the div-page with iframes. But I could not make that work.

The test is that I send some Form data back to the page. For that I am using classic ASP. 
The red squares represent images.

.

**Example 1.**  (See arxfoto.se/Test/_2divs.asp)

With the divs on *one simple page* it is working **OK**, see code example below.

The sent data is readable both in the body and in the wanted div.

There are some **issues** for later work:

1. I would have liked the leftnav div to have a centered content…
2. If I narrow the browser page there comes no horizontal scrollbar but div mainpage jumps down under div leftnav…

.

**Example 2.**  (See arxfoto.se/Test/_2divs_include.asp)

Same divs but as *included* files, which **is more like how I will use it.**

The POSTing of data is OK.

**Problems:**

1. Div leftnav looses the background color.
2. Div mainpage is no longer on top. It falls deep down.

.

**Example 3.** (See arxfoto.se/Test/_2iframes.asp)

But with iframes I cannot make it. I cannot send data to the page and certainly not to any iframe.

No jumps when narrowing browser page which is good.

But the scrollbars are constantly on?

I have been told that to set in the Form ‘target=”[name of iframe]”’ should send the data to the iframe. And ‘target=”_self”’ should send it back to the sending page (all in combination with ‘action=””’).

But I don’t seem at all to be able to activate the Form’s POSTing with iframes.

.

Can you see my mistakes?

Basic newbie question:
 **Should I continue with divs (+# include files) or with iframes for this frame layout?**

.

Code:

Example 1, (See arxfoto.se/Test/_2divs.asp) , 2 divs in one page:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>2 divs</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height: 100vh
    }
    #Leftnav {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding-top:15px;
        padding-left:15px;
        background:lightgrey;
        width:220px;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        border:1px solid #888;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    /*  display: flex;
        justify-content: center; */
    }
    #mainpanel {
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        background: lightblue;
        border:1px solid #888;
        width: 74%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 20px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    }

    #square {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center; 
    }
    #bigsquare {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background: red;
    }

</style>
<%
Dim msg
msg = request.form("ctrltest")
%>
</head>

<body>
this is the body<br>
<%
response.write "Msg = " & msg & "<br>"
%>
<div id="Leftnav"> 
this is &lt;div&gt;leftnav&lt;/div&gt;<br><br>
<div>
<Form name='Sending' method='POST' action='' target='_self'>
<a href='javascript:document.Sending.submit()'>
<div id ="square"><br>click!</div> </a>
<input type='hidden' name='ctrltest' value='Sent'>
</Form>
Send a message.
</div>
</div>

<div id="mainpanel">
    this is &lt;div&gt;mainpanel&lt;/div&gt<br><br>
    <%
    response.write "Msg = " & msg & "<br><br>"
    if msg = "Sent" then
    %>
        <div id="bigsquare"></div>
        The message was received.
    <%
    end if  
    %>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Example 2, (See arxfoto.se/Test/_2divs_include.asp), 2 divs included to a page:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>2 divs include</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height: 100vh
    }
    #leftnav,
    #mainpanel {
    float: left;
    height:100vh;
}
    #Leftnav {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding-top:15px;
        padding-left:15px;
        background:lightgrey;
        width:220px;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        border:1px solid #888;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #mainpanel {
        margin:0px 0px 0px 230px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        background: lightblue;
        border:1px solid #888;
        width: 74%;
        height: 100%;
       /* float: left; */
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 20px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    }
    /*div.a {font-size: 170%;} */

    #square {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center; 
    }
    #bigsquare {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background: red;
    }
</style>
<%
Dim msg
msg = request.form("ctrltest")
%>
</head>

<body>
this is the body<br>
<%
response.write "Msg = " & msg & "<br>"
%>

<div id="leftnav">
    <br>this is &lt;div&gt;leftnav&lt;/div&gt<br>
    <!-- #include file="_leftnav.asp" -->
</div>

<div id="mainpanel">
    this is &lt;div&gt;mainpanel&lt;/div&gt<br>
    <!-- #include file="_mainpanel.asp" -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example 3 : 
 (See arxfoto.se/Test/_2iframes.asp)

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>2 iframes</title>
<%
Dim msg
msg = request.form("Ctrltest")

%>
<style type="text/css">
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#main_block {
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#leftnav {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: lightgrey;
}

#mainpanel {
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px); 
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px); 
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    background:lightblue;
}
#leftnav,
#mainpanel {
    float: left;
    height:100vh;
}
iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main_block">
    This is the body<br>
    <%
    response.write "Msg = " & msg & "<br>"    
    %>
    This is leftnav iframe: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is mainpanel iframe:<br>
    <iframe id="leftnav" src="_leftnav.asp" ></iframe>
    <iframe id="mainpanel" src="_mainpanel.asp"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example 2 and 3, Imported to iframe “leftnav”, (and included to div) as **_leftnav.asp**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Leftnav iframe</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin:0;
        padding:15px;
        height: 100vh;
    }
     #square {
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center; 
    }   
</style>
</head>

<body>

<Form name='Sending' method='POST' action=''>  <!-- target='_self'> -->
<a href='javascript:document.Sending.submit()'>
<div id ="square"><br>click!</div> </a>
<input type='hidden' name='ctrltest' value='Sent'>
</Form>
Send a message.
</body>
</html>
```

Example 2 and 3, Imported to iframe “mainpage”, (and included to div) as **_mainpage.asp**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>mainpage iframe</title>
<style type="text/css">
 body {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin:0;
        padding:10;
        height: 100vh
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <%
    response.write "Msg = " & msg & "<br>"
    if msg = "Sent" then
    %>
        <div id="bigsquare"></div>
        The message was received.
    <%
    end if  
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should continue with divs

Comment: Thanks! Divs it is! Then I have some problems in Example 2...

Comment: The problems in Example 2 was handled like this: 
1. The grey background color was set in CSS in the #include file **_leftnav1.asp** instead of in the main file.
2. To level the divs I put them into a table.
See **arxfoto.se/Test/_2divs_include3.asp**,  #including files **_leftnav1.asp** and **_mainpanel1.asp**.
Seems to work fine for now!